# Why following code generates deadlock

Tags: multithreading, go, channel

Golang newbie here. Can somebody explain why the following code generates a deadlock?

I am aware of sending true to boolean <- done channel but I don't want to use it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg2 sync.WaitGroup

func producer2(c chan<- int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
        fmt.Println("Producer Writing to chan %d", i)
        c <- i
    }
}

func consumer2(c <-chan int) {
    defer wg2.Done()
    fmt.Println("Consumer Got value %d", <-c)

}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    wg2.Add(5)
    fmt.Println("Starting .... 1")
    go producer2(c)
    go consumer2(c)
    fmt.Println("Starting .... 2")

    wg2.Wait()
}
```

Following is my understanding and I know that it is wrong:

1. The channel will be blocked the moment 0 is written to it within the
   loop of producer function
2. So I expect channel to be emptied by the
   consumer afterwards.
3. As the channel is emptied in the step 2,
   producer function can again put in another value and then get
   blocked and steps 2 repeats again.

Comment: you are sending message to channel five times, but consuming channel only once.
the producer2 goroutine will be blocked until rest of the four message will be consumed.

Comment: and also, your usage of `sync.WaitGroup` is wrong since it calls `Add(5)` but calls  `Done()` only once.

Comment: @ymonad I added my understanding. Can you please correct me where I am going wrong ?  Reg.  Add(5) - I am expecting Done() to be called 5 times when consumer executes 5 times

Comment: In step 3, you mention that that step 2 would repeat again, but that's not true, the consumer in your code, only consumes once.

Answer (score 3):

Your original deadlock is caused by `wg2.Add(5)`, you were waiting for 5 goroutines to finish, but only one did; you called `wg2.Done()` once. Change this to `wg2.Add(1)`, and your program will run without error.

However, I suspect that you intended to consume all the values in the channel not just one as you do. If you change consumer function to:

```
func consumer2(c <-chan int) {
    defer wg2.Done()
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Printf("Consumer Got value %d\n", i)
    }
}
```

You will get another deadlock because the channel is not closed in producer function, and consumer is waiting for more values that never arrive. Adding `close(c)` to the producer function will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

### Why it error?

Running your code gets the following error:

```
➜  gochannel go run dl.go
Starting .... 1
Starting .... 2
Producer Writing to chan 0
Consumer Got value 0
Producer Writing to chan 1
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Here is why:

There are three goroutines in your code: `main`,`producer2` and `consumer2`. When it runs,

- `producer2` sends a number `0` to the channel
- `consumer2` recives `0` from the channel, and **exits**
- `producer2` sends `1` to the channel, but **no one is consuming**, since `consumer2` already exits
- `producer2` is **waiting**
- `main` executes `wg2.Wait()`, but not all waitgroup are closed. So **main is waiting**

Two goroutines are waiting here, does nothing, and nothing will be done no matter how long you wait. **It is a deadlock!** Golang detects it and panic.

There are two concepts you are confused here:

1. how waitgourp works
2. how to receive all values from a channel

I'll explain them here briefly, there are alreay many articles out there on the internet.

#### how waitgroup works

`WaitGroup` if a way to wait for all groutine to finish. When running goroutines in the background, it's important to know when all of them quits, then certain action can be conducted.

In your case, we run two goroutines, so at the beginning we should set `wg2.Add(2)`, and each goroutine should add `wg2.Done()` to notify it is done.

#### Receive data from a channel

When receiving data from a channel. If you know exactly how many data it will send, use `for` loop this way:

```
for i:=0; i<N; i++ {
    data = <-c
    process(data)
}
```

Otherwise use it this way:

```
for data := range c {
    process(data)
}
```

Also, **Don't forget to close channel when there is no more data to send.**

### How to fix it?

With the above explanation, the code can be fixed as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg2 sync.WaitGroup

func producer2(c chan<- int) {
    defer wg2.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        fmt.Printf("Producer Writing to chan %d\n", i)
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
}

func consumer2(c <-chan int) {
    defer wg2.Done()
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Printf("Consumer Got value %d\n", i)
    }

}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    wg2.Add(2)
    fmt.Println("Starting .... 1")
    go producer2(c)
    go consumer2(c)
    fmt.Println("Starting .... 2")

    wg2.Wait()
}
```

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/CtEIeX6rKi) is another possible way to fix it.

### The expected output

Fixed code gives the following output:

```
➜  gochannel go run dl.go
Starting .... 1
Starting .... 2
Producer Writing to chan 0
Consumer Got value 0
Producer Writing to chan 1
Consumer Got value 1
Producer Writing to chan 2
Consumer Got value 2
Producer Writing to chan 3
Consumer Got value 3
Producer Writing to chan 4
Consumer Got value 4
```